# PHP copying files from one location to the other

Tags: php, file-upload

not working with mp3 files ,,, working fine with text and image files

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {   

        echo "<br><br>user file uploading</br></br>";
        echo "Name : <font color='green'>".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]."</font>";
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "Type :<font color='green'>".$_FILES['userfile']['type']."</font>";
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "Size :<font color='green'>".($_FILES['userfile']['size']/1024)."</font>";
        echo "<br><br>";

        if (file_exists("G:/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"])) 
            {
                echo "<font color='red'>".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"] . " already exists.                   </font>";
            } 
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],"G:/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
            echo "<font color='blue'>Stored in: " . "G:/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]."</font>";
        }

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the copy isn't working? It looks like the problem is with uploading. Maybe your server has a limit on uploaded file size.

Comment: have you checked `$_FILE['userfile']['error']` for the MP3 file?

Comment: The 1980s is asking for its deprecated `font` tag back!!!

Comment: its returning 1 what is this mean

Comment: whats the problem wth uploading @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

The MP3 files are too big. The list of error codes can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). For `1` it says:

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>
> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the [**upload_max_filesize**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) directive in php.ini.

Increase the setting in `php.ini` to allow bigger files to be uploaded.